# web scraping unable to get all data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried accessing wit multiple ways to orpi's website and with each program, I have made, and each request returns only the data on available on HTML which is the navbar and some useless info, I'm trying to get any info for any housing but the part including the housing info is not getting fetched

This is the page I'm trying to get data from this [link](https://www.orpi.com/recherche/rent?transaction=rent&resultUrl=&realEstateTypes%5B0%5D=maison&realEstateTypes%5B1%5D=appartement&realEstateTypes%5B2%5D=terrain&realEstateTypes%5B3%5D=immeuble&realEstateTypes%5B4%5D=stationnement&agency=&minSurface=&maxSurface=&newBuild=&oldBuild=&minPrice=&maxPrice=&sort=date-down&layoutType=mixte&nbBedrooms=&page=&minLotSurface=&maxLotSurface=&minStoryLocation=&maxStoryLocation=)

and i'm trying to get any thing included in

please i've tried with these libraries and nothing is getting fetched: **scrapy**, **beautifulsoup**, requests from **nodejs**, requests from **python**.

here are some codes i have tried :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.orpi.com/recherche/buy?transaction=buy&resultUrl=&agency=&minSurface=&maxSurface=&newBuild=&oldBuild=&minPrice=&maxPrice=&sort=date-down&layoutType=mixte&nbBedrooms=&page=&minLotSurface=&maxLotSurface=&minStoryLocation=&maxStoryLocation=')

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())

#stories = []
#
#for a in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'u-mt-md'}):
#    stories.append([a])
#
#print stories[0]




#article = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'u-mt-md'})

#one_article = article.find('a', class_='u-link-unstyled c-overlay__link').text

#html = article.prettify()

#print(article)
```

with scrapy :

```
import scrapy
import pprint

class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Orpi'
    start_urls = ['https://www.orpi.com/recherche/buy?transaction=buy&resultUrl=&agency=&minSurface=&maxSurface=&newBuild=&oldBuild=&minPrice=&maxPrice=&sort=date-down&layoutType=mixte&nbBedrooms=&page=&minLotSurface=&maxLotSurface=&minStoryLocation=&maxStoryLocation=']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {}
        products = response.css('div.o-grid__col o-grid__col--8')
        for product in products:
            for p in product.css('div.o-grid__col u-flex u-flex-column'):
                yield {
                    'Images' : p.css('img.c-overlay__zoom u-cover::attr(src)').getall(),
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # Or Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.orpi.com/recherche/rent?transaction=rent&resultUrl=&realEstateTypes%5B0%5D=maison&realEstateTypes%5B1%5D=appartement&realEstateTypes%5B2%5D=terrain&realEstateTypes%5B3%5D=immeuble&realEstateTypes%5B4%5D=stationnement&agency=&minSurface=&maxSurface=&newBuild=&oldBuild=&minPrice=&maxPrice=&sort=date-down&layoutType=mixte&nbBedrooms=&page=&minLotSurface=&maxLotSurface=&minStoryLocation=&maxStoryLocation=")

sleep(3)
html = driver.page_source    
driver.quit()
# Do your stuff with html
```

Replace [driver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers) if you have other browser.

The page was loaded with javascript. You need delay to get result.

Comment: Your solution works infact, i was wondering if you would know actually why this wasn't possible with the other libraries ? Is it to be done that way ? are they intentionally blocking bots ?

Comment: No they are not blocking bots. Server sends you html with script, then browser executes the script and shows result. Selenium emulates browser and executes script. delay is needed for execution time. Also why did you accept, then unaccept and again accept my answer?

Comment: i did not do it on purpose i accepted it the second i saw i unaccepted it :=)